# C# service onCustomCommand with parameters?

Tags: c#, service, parameters, servicecontroller

I am currently trying to implement a service that runs a special command that does something with arguments passed, for example: file paths. I am using the `cmd` command:

`sc control "ServiceName" 128`

However, this command doesn't provide any way for me to input arguments. The method is as below:

```
    protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
    {
        switch(command)
        {
            case 128:
                Command.StartProcess(3);
                LogWriter.WriteLog("Next output: ");
                Command.StartProcess(4);
                break;
            case 129:
                // input extension, output extension, key id , working path
                try
                {
                    test t1 = new test();
                    t1.readLog(@"C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\success.txt");
                    LogWriter.WriteLog(t1.input);
                    LogWriter.WriteLog(t1.output);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    LogWriter.WriteLog(e.ToString());
                }
                finally { LogWriter.WriteLog("abc"); }
                //LogWriter.WriteLog(t1.output + "def");
                break;
        }
    }
```

The only argument i can input is the `int` `command` for the method. I would like to input a `folder path` for `t1.readLog();`. In the above code, I have to hard code the path which isn't flexible and troublesome. So, is there anyway to work this out?

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the wrong method for this. Take a look at [ServiceBase.OnStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart(v=vs.110).aspx).
It gets array of arguments that can be set in command line like this:

```
sc start MyService arg1 arg2
```

Parse args array as you want:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   var path = args[0];
   var someParameter = args[1];
}
```

> Process initialization arguments for the service in the OnStart
>   method, not in the Main method. The arguments in the args parameter
>   array can be set manually in the properties window for the service in
>   the Services console